# How to convert text to arithmetic expression

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to build text base calculator in c#

Let suppose I have text

> Add two plus three. its arithmetic
>   expression will be (2+3)
>
> Add five thousand two hundred to four
>   hundred thirty two divided by thirty
>   four.((5200+430)/34).
>
> Add three million to seven million
>   then add five then
>   two.(((3000000+7000000)+5)+2)

And so on.

What will be the algorithm to do this?

Comment: What is the code you have written so far?

Comment: I do not code yet i am just thinking algorithm to acheive this behaviour.

Comment: one of the more significant problems you re going to face is tht strings like
"Add five thousand two hundred to four hundred thirty two divided by thirty four" are ambiguous.  it could mean 5200+(430/34) or (5200+430)/34.

Comment: @Yaur i think the order of operations would be from left to right for all operators? That would fix the ambiguity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you have to do parsing of your text. The idea is to find out tokens(text of interest) from you string. Lets suppose, the text is Add two plus three, you find separate tokens, lets say the tokens you find are `Add, two, plus, three`. Replace tokens with your predefined numbers, for example token `two` `= 2` and so on. Replace arithematic text with arithematic operators for example `Add = +` and so on. And finally execute the calculated expression to get the result.